# PROCESS BUILDER: Stacking Scheduled Actions on a Single Node

Tags: apex, process-builder, scheduled-job

Trying to set up scheduled actions on a process builder and have them stacked 3 days out from a Date Field on the opportunity.

```
If(x == true) then run Schedule 1, after schedule 1 runs and conditions are same, run 2, etc.
```

**The Main Question**

will my 2 and 3rd schedules be skipped after the firs schedule is evaluated? When I checked the paused flows, there was only one in there, which makes sense if it has to process that first scheduled action before it pauses on the second scheduled action. I'm assuming that 3 days out I would see a new scheduled process in the paused interviews.

Here is a screen shot of the process builder:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The actions are all contained in a single flow ("interview"). You'll only see at most one instance of this builder per record. It will progress to the next step automatically.